# How do I call the Magento API SOAP V2 with multiple complex filters to the same field?

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, soap, soap-api-v2, soap-api

How do I call the Magento API SOAP V2 with multiple complex filters to the same field? In my case I use the [salesOrderList](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html) function.

This source code does not work:

```
$params = array(array(
        'complex_filter' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'increment_id',
                'value' => array(
                    'key' => 'nlike',
                    'value' => 'a_%'
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'increment_id',
                'value' => array(
                    'key' => 'nlike',
                    'value' => 'e_%'
                ),
            ),
        )
    ));

$result = $client->__call('salesOrderList', $params);
```

The final sql code only contains:

```
AND (increment_id NOT LIKE 'a_%')
```

But it should contain:

```
AND (increment_id NOT LIKE 'a_%') AND (increment_id NOT LIKE 'e_%')
```

For SQL it doesn't matter how many 'LIKE's I apply to a field?!!

**What am I doing wrong?**